Trouble with short mp3s using Flutter audioplayers plugin
I'm playing mp3s in Flutter code a trivial way, using the dependencies line audioplayers: ^6.0.0 in my pubspec.yaml:
import 'package:audioplayers/audioplayers.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


void main() async {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final player = AudioPlayer();

    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child:Column(
            children: [
              SizedBox(height: 100,),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () async {
                    await player.play(AssetSource('sfx/click2.mp3'));
                }, 
                child: Text('Click 2!'),
              ),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () async {
                    await player.play(AssetSource('sfx/click3.mp3'));
                }, 
                child: Text('Click 3!'),
              )
            ]
          )
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Click3 works, but Click2 throws this error:
PlatformException (PlatformException(AndroidAudioError, Failed to set source. For troubleshooting, see:
https://github.com/bluefireteam/audioplayers/blob/main/troubleshooting.md, MEDIA_ERROR_UNKNOWN {what:1}, MEDIA_ERROR_SYSTEM, null))

click2.mp3 was made from click3.mp3 by reducing the wave to ~30 milliseconds, from ~300 milliseconds, removing only trailing silence from the clip. Both clips play fine on a typical mp3 player, like Windows Media Player.
Okay, so it's no biggie adding a 100ms of silence to a clip, but aside from that workaround, does anyone see something I may be missing? I didn't find any info on this in the audioplayers docs, or the troubleshooting link referenced in the exception description.
